# How to get elements elements from concatenated array in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to get first 5 elements from concatenated array in BigQuery

```
SELECT id, ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(a  LIMIT 5) FROM (

      SELECT 1 as id, ARRAY [6,7,8,9] a
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 1 ,ARRAY [2,3,4,5] 
)
GROUP BY 1
```

This query looks like correct but returns full array ignoring `LIMIT`.
What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_concat_agg), the LIMIT option applies to the number of input arrays, not to the number of elements in the arrays.

There does not seem to be a builtin BigQuery function for returning a slice of an array. So, re-using some of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54835184/how-can-i-get-a-slice-of-an-array-in-bigquery-standard-sql), the following worked for me in standard SQL to return just the first 5 elements from the concatenated array:

```
SELECT id, ARRAY(SELECT ix FROM UNNEST(arr) ix
                 WITH OFFSET INDEX
                 WHERE index BETWEEN 0 AND 4 ORDER BY index)
FROM ( SELECT id,
       ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(a) AS arr
       FROM ( SELECT 1 as id, ARRAY [6,7,8,9] a
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 1 ,ARRAY [2,3,4,5] )
       GROUP BY id)
```

Comment: Thank you for idea! I forgot about UDF. Better to use is with simple `slice` in JS)